# Problems installing Subversion Perl

Tags: perl, svn, dependencies, rpm

I'm trying to setup Bugzilla's VCS integration with Subversion.
I've installed the CollabNet Subversion client CollabNetSubversion-client-1.6.16-1.i386.rpm which installs its libs to /opt/CollabNet_Subversion.

Now I want to install the subversion-perl-1.6.16-2.4.i586.rpm package but the RPM commandline tool fails with dependency issues:

```
subversion = 1.6.16 is needed by subversion-perl-1.6.16-2.4.i586
libsvn_client-1.so.0 is needed by subversion-perl-1.6.16-2.4.i586
libsvn_delta-1.so.0 is needed by subversion-perl-1.6.16-2.4.i586
libsvn_diff-1.so.0 is needed by subversion-perl-1.6.16-2.4.i586
libsvn_fs-1.so.0 is needed by subversion-perl-1.6.16-2.4.i586
libsvn_ra-1.so.0 is needed by subversion-perl-1.6.16-2.4.i586
libsvn_repos-1.so.0 is needed by subversion-perl-1.6.16-2.4.i586
libsvn_subr-1.so.0 is needed by subversion-perl-1.6.16-2.4.i586
libsvn_wc-1.so.0 is needed by subversion-perl-1.6.16-2.4.i586
```

Subversion 1.6.16 is installed but it seems to be the wrong location.
What do I have to do to resolve these dependency issues?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you're using a 3rd party package (3rd party compared to your OS vendor) and it doesn't integrate with the rest of your OS vendor's packages.

The simple solution would be to use the subversion rpm supplied by your OS vendor.  If possible do that because getting the Subversion/Perl bindings working is tricky and its best if you get both SVN and Perl from the same supplier.  Since it looks like the CollabNet package installs to its own separate location you can *probably* install the OS Subversion alongside and they won't interfere.

Otherwise, you can compile and install the Subversion bindings manually using [Alien::SVN](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Alien::SVN).  Its ok that the version of SVN in Alien::SVN and the version you've installed don't exactly match and it will not collide with either package.